# Run a command using custom toolbar button?

Tags: notepad++, custom-controls, customization

I only know how to create custom buttons using Customize Toolbar plugin for macros or the existing menu entries.

But what if I need a button for a particular command to run? For example: `cmd /c “$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)”`

Is there a way to do so? Maybe using the optional toolbarIcons.xml file or something?

BTW I know I can create a shortcut for the command, and in fact, I already did, but I’d like to have a toolbar button in addition to that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After creating a new shortcut in Run Commands the new Run menu entry appear and we use this new entry for our button.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean? How did you add it to the toolbar?